# Generate a CSR with no country, state or Organizational Unit

Tags: openssl, certificate, csr

I need to generate a CSR which I've done many times. However the certificate I'm trying to generate it for only has Subject values for the CN, OU and DC . OpenSSL doesn't let you leave the State, City or O values blank; it just auto-fills them with defaults and you can't erase that.

How can I generates CSRs with these weird values?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 9):

If you want to leave some field out then type a period `.`

If you want to try something else you could try [xca](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/). It is built on top of openssl and have a nice GUI. Documentation can be found [here](http://xca.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with the use of certtool - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GnuTLS